# Moving parent item and create alias

Tags: powershell-extensions

I'm working on cleaning up sitecore items where i have bunch of items sitting under various nodes so what i'm trying to archive is to move all under single folder and create alias on the original path.

For instance,

**Path:** `/products/devices/brand/samsung/s10`

- Products

  - Devices

    - Brand

      - **Samsung** - Item

        - S10 - Alias
        - S10Plus - Alias
      - **Nokia** - Item

        - Nokia82 - Alias
        - Nokia2 - Alias

**New Structure**

**Path :** `/brands/`

- Brands

  - Samsung
  - Nokia

How can i archive this by moving the item under brands folder while keeping the same id and other side create alias pointing to new location?

I have managed to move phones and create alias e.g. nokia2 but not sure how to move the parent item and replace with alias.

I've tried using powershell, see below but didn't work.

```
Copy-Item -Path 'master:/sitecore/content/Home/Products/Devices/Brand/Samsung/s10' -Destination 'master:/sitecore/content/Home/Brands/' -TransferOptions 0
```

Sitecore version 9.3

Comment: You should be using Move-Item instead of Copy-Item
`Move-Item -Path "master:\content\home\Demo" -Destination "master:\content\home\Demo1"`. Refer - https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/working-with-items#command-introduction

Comment: but i would like to keep the child items under old structure as those are old alias items.

Comment: ... if you move a parent item, the children under it are automatically "moved"

Comment: @MarkCassidy technically yes but trying to find logical/best solution to sort this out.